# generalised limiting distribution for periodic markov chain

Tags: markov-process, stationarity

The usual conditions for a Markov chain to have a limiting distribution includes aperiodicity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity

However, in some contexts it would be convenient to generalise the concept of limiting distribution to also apply to periodic Markov chain. The generalised limiting distribution would simply be the average over a whole period.

Surely I'm not the first to think along these lines. Does anyone have a better term and/or reference to this concept?

Comment: See Corollary 6 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ps/1099928648)

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.